# Django Rest Framework: Choosing what to serialize

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to the Django-REST Framework, and currently I am writing my serializers.Thing is, it seems like serializers create the mapping for JSON. That is, whatever I am serializing gets converted to JSON in my view(correct me if I am wrong).

I am writing an API that needs to return a request Response via JSON. Thing is, I have serializer fields from multiple apps that I want to use to return one Response in json format.

I looked at the django-rest tutorials, and they didn't really cover this topic. How would you pick and choose the objects you want to send out in a single response?

Comment: I suggest you to go through the documentation once again, you might find what you need. Look at these pages; serializers, serializer fields and serializer relations.